# Flutter: Dynamically render variable length Text with a TextField inside it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dynamic-length piece of text with a blank (TextField) somewhere in its midst to be filled in by the user, and I want to render it correctly.  Here's what I'm trying to do (Recreated the middle version with two static Text widgets and Wrap). How could I achieve this?

[Different text lengths and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8i7n.png)

Comment: Perhaps this? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan-class.html

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!